# Template literals (Template strings) not working on IE

Tags: javascript, json

I've had somebody doing this piece of code for me. It works perfectly on all browser. Except, of course, Internet Explorer. I've read about template literals and the problem with backticks and IE, but I'm not entirely sure on how to implement a solution to my case. Here's the code:

```
var products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
var i = 0;
var html = "";
$.each(products, function(index, val) {
console.log(val);
 var img_quo = val.img;
var new_img = img_quo.substring(1, img_quo.length);

html += `<div style="width: 100%;margin: 0px;text-align: center;display: block;padding-bottom: 0px;float: left;" id="item_div_`+i+`">
<div class="input_fields_wrap_`+i+`"     style="background: #EDEDED;    display: inline-block;    border-radius: 45px;    width: 92%;    padding: 15px 20px;     margin: 0 0 8px;">

<div id="img-block">
<a href="/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=`+decodeURIComponent(val.product_code)+`"><img src="`+new_img+`" alt="item" height="auto" width="auto"></a>
</div>

<div id="input-block-half" style="display:none;">
<input class="input-field" name="Item Number" value="`+decodeURIComponent(val.product_code)+`" type="text" required=""></div>

<div id="input-block">
<input class="input-field" name="Item Name" value="`+val.name+`" type="text"></div>

<div id="input-block-price">
<input class="input-field" name="Item Price" value="`+$.trim(val.price)+`" type="text" readonly></div>

<div id="input-block-qty">
<input class="input-field-qty" name="Quantity" value="`+val.qty+`" type="number" required=""></div>

<div id="input-block-remove">
<span class="input-text" onclick="removeItem(`+i+`,'`+decodeURIComponent(val.product_code)+`')"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/IAB7ZrK.png" style="margin-top: 11px; cursor:pointer;"></span></div>
</div>`;
i++;
});
$('.input_fields_wrap').html(html);
```

Comment: Simply get rid of the template literals, they aren't used properly anyway. If you don't want that, have Babel transpile your code.

Comment: Babel transpile got rid of those backticks. Code works now. Thanks!

Comment: The only use for template literals, AFAIK, is to get rid of those `" + expression + "` by using `${expression}` instead. If you are using the `+`s, then just get rid of them, otherwise use them like: `\`lorem "epsum" ${someValue}. More lorem ipsum\``

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The other use-case is to have newline characters inside a string. If the OP replaces his `\`` all with `'` there would be a syntax error since his strings container newlines. He would need to replace those with `\n` as well to switch to regular strings.

Answer (score 1):

## Template literals

Template literals can contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces. `${expression}`.

```js
let a = 'Hello';
let b = 'world'
let c = new Date();

console.log(`${a} ${b} right now is ${c}`);
```

Your string should look like this:

```
let strg = `<div style="width: 100%;margin: 0px;text-align: center;display: block;padding-bottom: 0px;float: left;" id="item_div_${i}">
    <div class="input_fields_wrap_${i}" style="background: #EDEDED; display: inline-block; border-radius: 45px; width: 92%; padding: 15px 20px; margin: 0 0 8px;">

    <div id="img-block">
    <a href="/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=${decodeURIComponent(val.product_code)}"><img src="${new_img}" alt="item" height="auto" width="auto"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="input-block-half" style="display:none;">
    <input class="input-field" name="Item Number" value="${decodeURIComponent(val.product_code)}" type="text" required=""></div>

    <div id="input-block">
    <input class="input-field" name="Item Name" value="${val.name}" type="text"></div>

    <div id="input-block-price">
    <input class="input-field" name="Item Price" value="${$.trim(val.price)}" type="text" readonly></div>

    <div id="input-block-qty">
    <input class="input-field-qty" name="Quantity" value="${val.qty}" type="number" required=""></div>

    <div id="input-block-remove">
    <span class="input-text" onclick="removeItem(${i}, '${decodeURIComponent(val.product_code)}')"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/IAB7ZrK.png" style="margin-top: 11px; cursor:pointer;"></span></div>
    </div>`
```

For **IE** support it's better to use `"blabla" + something + "bla"`

Comment: `${val.name+}` and others should probably be `${val.name}`.